# how to redirect a page from flash using php

Tags: php, flash, web-applications

Hello community I have the following scenario.

I have a swf with a button that sends a URL request to a php file. Which is the following.

```
    <?php
      session_start();

      if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){

        header ('Location: http://mydomain.com/test/reroute.php');
        exit();
      }
   ?>
```

However, the php file does not reroute to the desired page. Am I missing something?

Thank you very much,

Comment: How is `$_SESSION['user']` getting set?

Comment: Looks good to me. Maybe `$_SESSION['user']` is not being set? You could do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see what is in the $_SESSION.

Comment: can you show some of your actionscript and does the problem seem to be that the actionscript is not following the redirect or that php is not sending the redirect correctly?

Comment: Does the php file redirect correctly when you open it directly from the browser?

Comment: An URL request from **Flash** will not redirect (=change the URL) of the **page**, the SWF is embedded into without further coding. You will need to use the JS facilities

Comment: Eugen, you were right. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go to a page from flash, you need to do [`navigateToURL`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html) as follows:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://mydomain.com/test/reroute.php"), "_self");
```

**EDIT**
To softcode the redirect url, I suggest you do this (I suspect this is more relevant to what you're looking for)

```
private var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();

private function init():void {
    //In the class initialize handler
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, redirectReceived);
}

private function redirectReceived(e:Event):void {
    if(StringUtil.trim(e.target.data).length > 0) {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(e.target.data), "_self");
    }
}

private function buttonClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    loader.load(new URLRequest("http://path_to_the_php_which_tells_you_where_to_redirect"));
}
```

And the php which tells you where to redirect will be like this:

```
<?php
      session_start();

      if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){

        echo('Location: http://mydomain.com/test/reroute.php');

      }
?>
```